# How to quickly populate/create objects in java?

Tags: java, oop, object

So I am creating on Eclipse an Android app backend and I have let us say a "Dog" class and that class is attached to an "Activity" class. So I would like to create about 150 dog objects each with their own activities and descriptions which one day users can look at and don't have to recreate. 
How should I go about creating, once and for all, the 150 dogs and their corresponding 50 activities? What is the standard? Do people write in code "new Dog.. new Dog.. new Dog" with all the argument in a method which they never call again once it has all been saved to XML or is there a cleaner way to do it?

Edit: Sorry, I wasn't precise enough. I now how to make data persistent. I am just looking at an easy way to create 150 different instances of dogs with different parameters in each object.

Comment: I recommend having a look at creational design patterns:
https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/creational_patterns.
These are some best practice software design patterns to create objects.

Comment: @Tagas I dont think that's what he's asking...

Comment: `which one day users can look` and you want to make the data persistent? That's completely different question

Answer (score 1):

You could initialize your Objects in a for-loop and save them into an ArrayList:

```
int dogNumber = 150;
ArrayList<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<Dog>();
for (int i = 0; i < dogNumber; i++){
    dogs.add(new Dog());
}
```

This will give you a List containing 150 dogs. You could create your activities in a similar fashion.

For informations on ArrayList methods: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: That would in fact create 150 Dogs but they would all be objects with the same parameters . Sorry I wasn't precise enough, I'd need to have a dog called Doberman, another Husky etc...

Comment: You could create dogs with randomly chosen parameters (e.g. for race) you initialize with all possible races you want. Say your races are saved in a String Array String[] races = {Doberman, Husky,...} you can initialize your dogs with these parameters with random indexes of you races Array, eg dogs.add(new Dog(races[some random index])). You might want to look into a random generator like this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

Comment: If you want to initialize each dog with a specific race or trait you choose there is no "clean way" to do it.

Comment: Thank you TA, that's what I feared

Answer (score 0):

You can use dog builder to create dogs

```
public class Dog {
    private String active;

    public String getActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(String active) {
        this.active = active;
    }


    public static final class DogBuilder {
        private String active;

        private DogBuilder() {
        }

        public static DogBuilder aDog() {
            return new DogBuilder();
        }

        public DogBuilder withActive(String active) {
            this.active = active;
            return this;
        }

        public Dog build() {
            Dog dog = new Dog();
            dog.setActive(active);
            return dog;
        }
    }
}
```

And use the builder like:

```
public void test(){
    Dog dog = Dog.DogBuilder.aDog().withActive("a").build();
}
```

This is the  [Domain-Driven Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design). You also can search for more details.

The object itself has the activity and status

Comment: 'This is the Domain-Driven Design.' - a "slight"  exaggeration I think... (the builder pattern has very very little to do with DDD)